# Ember data this.store getting undefine

Tags: ember.js, ember-data

I want to add new record to store using emberdata.Js but not working 
 Here is my code

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>

<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
<meta name="description" content="ED: Reading" />

<script src="js/jquery-1.10.2.js"></script>
<script src="js/handlebars-1.1.2.js"></script>
<script src="js/ember-1.5.1.js"></script>
<script src="http://builds.emberjs.com/beta/ember-data.prod.js"></script>



<script type="text/javascript">

App = Ember.Application.create();

App.Store = DS.Store.extend({
revision: 12,
url: 'http://localhost/Ember/Demo2/'
});

App.Pull = DS.Model.extend({
title: DS.attr(),
url: DS.attr(),
});

App.Router.map(function(){
this.resource('pull');
});

var store = this.store;

//var obj = App.Pull.createRecord();



App.PullRoute = Ember.Route.extend({
model: 
    function() {
        store.createRecord('pull', {
title: 'Rails is Omakase',
url: 'Lorem ipsum'
});
    //return this.store.find('pull');
    //return App.Pull.find();
    //this.store.createobjects(response);
    }
});




</script>

</head>
<body>

<script type="text/x-handlebars">
 <h1>Welcome</h1>
 <div class="navbar-header">
      {{#link-to 'pull' classNames='navbar-brand'}}
        City List
      {{/link-to}} 
    </div>
 {{outlet}}
</script>

<script type="text/x-handlebars" data-template-name="pull">
 <h2>GetAllCityList</h2>
 <div class="navbar-header">
 <ul>
 {{#each model}}
    <li>{{title}}</li>
 {{/each}}
 </ul>
 </div>

</script>



</body>
</html>
```

I am trying to add record to store type of model on calling of model city but this.store is giving me undefined.

below is error in ember insepctor

```
Error while loading route: TypeError: Cannot read property 'createRecord' of undefined
at App.PullRoute.Ember.Route.extend.model   (http://localhost/Ember/Demo2/storedemo.html:42:9)
at superWrapper [as model] (http://localhost/Ember/Demo2/js/ember-1.5.1.js:1292:16)
at Ember.Route.Ember.Object.extend.deserialize (http://localhost/Ember/Demo2/js/ember-1.5.1.js:36570:19)
at http://localhost/Ember/Demo2/js/ember-1.5.1.js:32972:57
at http://localhost/Ember/Demo2/js/ember-1.5.1.js:33464:19
at invokeResolver (http://localhost/Ember/Demo2/js/ember-1.5.1.js:9646:9)
at new Promise (http://localhost/Ember/Demo2/js/ember-1.5.1.js:9632:9)
at Router.async (http://localhost/Ember/Demo2/js/ember-1.5.1.js:33463:16)
at Object.HandlerInfo.runSharedModelHook (http://localhost/Ember/Demo2/js/ember-1.5.1.js:32971:16)
at Object.UnresolvedHandlerInfoByParam.getModel (http://localhost/Ember/Demo2/js/ember-1.5.1.js:33058:19)

>this.store
undefined
```

Answer (score 1):

Just FYI From [Ember models docs](https://guides.emberjs.com/v2.4.0/models/creating-updating-and-deleting-records/):

"The store object is available in controllers and routes using this.store"

I was running into this error because I was attempting to access the store from a component.js file.

Really helpful article on this problem from [Josh Farrant here](https://blog.farrant.me/how-to-access-the-store-from-within-an-ember-component/)

Answer (score 0):

You might use following way to create your record:

```
...
var obj = store.createRecord('pull', {
    title: 'Rails is Omakase',
    url: 'Lorem ipsum'
});    
obj.save().then(function(record){
    return record;
});
```

Comment: But the problem is store is undefined. So first we have to resolve that.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like a scoping issue. You're assigning 'var store = this.store;' in the scope of your application, but Ember.js creates new objects based on your extended definition of Ember.Route and so the scope for 'store' in App.PullRoute may be different than it appears.

Try this:

```
App.PullRoute = Ember.Route.extend({
model: function() {
        this.store.createRecord('pull', {
          title: 'Rails is Omakase',
          url: 'Lorem ipsum'
          });
     }
});
```

Comment: #corinna000 this.store i am getting undefined in ember inspector. So i think problem is with ember-data.js.

Comment: I am using latest ember.js from emberjs.com but still this.store not working for me.

Answer (score 0):

I don't see any issue. I did get the store returned when i tried it. I just created a jsbin in case you might want to check.

http://emberjs.jsbin.com/zesemuqe/1/edit

I did find two issues. 1. You sure are trying to create a record which gets it into the store. But you are not returning it.

```
App.PullRoute = Ember.Route.extend({
    model: function() {
        return this.store.createRecord('pull', {
            title: 'Rails is Omakase',
            url: 'Lorem ipsum'
        });
    }
});
```

2.Secondly, I can see that you are trying to loop over the model which is not an array and just an object, so handlebars does throw an error on that.

```
<script type="text/x-handlebars" data-template-name="pull">
    <ul>
        <li>{{title}}</li>
    </ul>
</script>
```

And I know it surely isn't the issue, but did you load all the dependencies correctly, the jsbin is missing them ?